# Drop a column from table problem (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, table-index

Unable to delete `[U_Family]` column from table below :

Table CREATE script:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users](
    [U_Id] [int] IDENTITY(101,1) NOT NULL,
    [U_Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [U_Family] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Users] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [U_Id] ASC
),
 CONSTRAINT [IX_UserIdUnique] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [U_UserId] ASC
)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Users(UserId)] ON [dbo].[Users] 
(
    [U_Id] ASC
)
INCLUDE ( [U_Name],
[U_Family]) ) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

error message :

> > 'Users' table
> >     - Unable to modify table.   The index 'IX_Users(UserId)' is dependent on
> >     column 'U_Family'. ALTER TABLE DROP
> >     COLUMN U_Family failed because one or
> >     more objects access this column.

I know that the problem is because of this index :

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Users(UserId)] ON [dbo].[Users] 
(
    [U_Id] ASC
)
INCLUDE ( [U_Name],
[U_Family])) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

but I never found a syntax to edit this index and remove `[U_Family]` from included columns.

I cannot delete this index because it is used by a foreign key constraint that I should not remove it.

any solution ????

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SQL Server 2008, you should be able to "re-create" your index and drop the existing one in a single command - try this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Users(UserId)] 
  ON [dbo].[Users]([U_Id] ASC) 
  WITH DROP_EXISTING
```

The `WITH DROP_EXISTING` should drop the "old" index with the included columns. Once that command has been run, you should be able to drop your column from the table.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to drop the index IX_Users and create a new one without U_Family.

Answer (score 0):

I used **sys.indexes** to delete the index and then drop the column:

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(max)

SELECT @sql = 'DROP INDEX ' + idx.NAME + ' ON tblName'
FROM sys.indexes idx
INNER JOIN sys.tables tbl ON idx.object_id = tbl.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.index_columns idxCol ON idx.index_id = idxCol.index_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns col ON idxCol.column_id = col.column_id
WHERE idx.type <> 0
    AND tbl.NAME = 'tblName'
    AND col.NAME = 'colName'

EXEC sp_executeSql @sql
GO

ALTER TABLE tblName
DROP COLUMN colName
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution and worked for me:

```
DECLARE @ConstraintName nvarchar(200)
SELECT @ConstraintName = Name FROM SYS.DEFAULT_CONSTRAINTS WHERE 
PARENT_OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('__TableName__') AND PARENT_COLUMN_ID = (SELECT 
column_id FROM sys.columns WHERE NAME = N'__ColumnName__' AND object_id = 
OBJECT_ID(N'__TableName__'))
IF @ConstraintName IS NOT NULL
   EXEC('ALTER TABLE __TableName__ DROP CONSTRAINT ' + @ConstraintName)
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM syscolumns WHERE id=object_id('__TableName__') AND 
name='__ColumnName__')
   EXEC('ALTER TABLE __TableName__ DROP COLUMN __ColumnName__')
```

Just replace `__TableName__` and `__ColumnName__`.